# Dynamic routing in mule

Tags: routes, mule, hotdeploy

I am pretty new to mule and am working on a dynamic routing using mule. At run time I am getting the port number where my service is hosted.

Please find my code below:

```
  <script:component doc:name="Script">
    <script:script engine="groovy">
      <![CDATA[
        String endpnt = reqUrl.prepareFile(requestUrl);
        message.setProperty('port', reqUrl.getPort(),org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope.INVOCATION);

       ]]>
    </script:script>
  </script:component>

<logger message="#[flowVars['port']]" level="INFO" doc:name="port" />

        <http:request config-ref="FlowRef"
                    path="/subflow" method="GET" doc:name="Invoke Dynamic service" />
```

The above script returns me the port number on which the service is hosted and am invoking the same using

```
<flow name="testFlow1">
    <http:listener config-ref="BaseRef" path="/subflow"
        doc:name="Eval" />
    <logger message="calling testFlow1 service" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />

    <http:request config-ref="ServiceMonProxy1" path="/"
        method="GET" doc:name="Credit validation"/>
</flow>
```

The problem is `"#[flowVars['port']]"` is not getting resolved at runtime and mule is throwing me an exception which says improper port

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Try to return the message in your script :

```
<script:component doc:name="Script">
<script:script engine="groovy">
  <![CDATA[
    String endpnt = reqUrl.prepareFile(requestUrl);
    message.setProperty('port', reqUrl.getPort(),org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope.INVOCATION);
    return message;
   ]]>
</script:script>
```

Hope it helps.

/Tony

Comment: I am able to get the value, but mule is not able to resolve the same at run-time.

Comment: Could you show the configuration reference, please ?

Comment: <logger message="#[flowVars['port']]" level="INFO" doc:name="port" /> prints the value of the port, but the same is not getting set when used in <http:request-config name="ServiceMonProxy1" host="0.0.0.0"
port="#[flowVars['port']]" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" />

Comment: I see, the problem with this configuration I guess is that the http configuration is loaded at the initialization of the flow. Your answering post what I was to suggest ;)

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer. Please find the below code

just replaced

```
<http:request config-ref="FlowRef"
               path="/subflow" method="GET" doc:name="Invoke Dynamic service" />
```

with

```
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="#[flowVars['port']]" path="a" doc:name="HTTP"/>
```

and it worked.